# Select muito lento, como melhorar?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Tenho uma tabela de cadastro de artesãos com cerca de 90 mil registros. Eu criei o SQL abaixo para me retornar o total de artesãos em cada uma das regiões que eles estão cadastrados. Apesar de funcionar, está lento, demorando mais de 30 segundos para retornar os registros.

Como posso melhorar?

```
    SELECT
        coordenacao.descricao AS nome, 
        COUNT(artesao.codigo) AS qtde
    FROM 
        municipio, artesao, coordenacaomunicipios, coordenacao
    WHERE 
        artesao.codMunicipio = municipio.codigo AND 
        coordenacaomunicipios.codMunicipio = municipio.codigo AND 
        coordenacaomunicipios.codCoordenacao = coordenacao.codigo AND 
        artesao.codStatus = 1
    GROUP BY 
        coordenacao.descricao
    ORDER BY 
        coordenacao.codigo
```

Comment: Funcionou algum das soluções abaixo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente criar os [índices de buscas mysql](http://www.webgoal.com.br/como-otimizar-consultas-no-mysql/).

```
ALTER TABLE municipio ADD INDEX(codigo); 
ALTER TABLE artesao ADD INDEX(codMunicipio); 
ALTER TABLE coordenacaomunicipios ADD INDEX(codMunicipio, codCoordenacao );  
ALTER TABLE coordenacao ADD INDEX(codigo, codStatus);
```

Comment: agora funcionou obrigado, criei todos os indices que vc falou e mais o indice ALTER TABLE status ADD INDEX(codigo);

Answer (score 4):

Tensa usar o `INNER JOIN` na junção das tabelas ao invés desse monte de `AND` no `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
        coordenacao.descricao AS nome, 
        COUNT(artesao.codigo) AS qtde
    FROM 
        municipio 
        INNER JOIN artesao ON municipio.codigo = artesao.codMunicipio
        INNER JOIN coordenacaomunicipios ON coordenacaomunicipios.codMunicipio = municipio.codigo
        INNER JOIN coordenacao ON coordenacaomunicipios.codCoordenacao = coordenacao.codigo
    WHERE 
        artesao.codStatus = 1
    GROUP BY 
        coordenacao.descricao
    ORDER BY 
        coordenacao.codigo
```

Comment: A principio isso vai dar no mesmo.

Comment: nenhuma das duas funcionou, criei os índices e uso o meu sql ou esse que você me passou, continua a mesma coisa "A mostrar registos de 0 - 24 (28 total, O Query demorou 32.6235 sec)"